# why is hadoop not placing the data in the directory specified in hdfs-site.xml

Tags: java, hadoop

I have configured the hadoop on multi node cluster using the michael noll tutorial(http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/). in which how to configure the hadoop first on individual nodes and then connect them.

What i really wanted was that the hadoop should place the data in the directory specified the hadoop.data.dir parameter in hdfs-site.xml.

hadoop.data.dir
  /djhadoop/hadoop-data-dir
  Data Directory.

but instead it is still placing the data blocks in the directory specified in the tmp directory  as given in core-site.xml:-

hadoop.tmp.dir
  /djhadoop/hadoop-tmp

Why is the hadoop not using the data directory specified in the hdfs-site.xml file and instead using the directory specified in core-site.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the property is **dfs.data.dir** and not hadoop.data.dir. Also make sure you have saved the changes and restarted the daemons in order to freeze the modifications.

Comment: I have same problem regarding the mapred.system.dir in hdfs-site.xml i want to set the directory for mapred files. do you know how ?

Comment: It should be in **mapred-site.xml**

Comment: i know it is in mapred-site.xml but the directory i specify in there is also not used there for storing the mapred -related files. Has the format changed like it did for dfs.name.dir from hadoop.name.dir in hadoop.0.20.

Comment: What is the path which you have given as its value?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never seen hadoop.name.dir.